# ¿Para qué sirve flush() en Kotlin?

Tags: android, funciones, kotlin

Al almacenar un archivo uso `FileOutputStream()`, después es posible utilizar `write()`, `flush()` y `close()`. El primer y tercer método se describen por si solos, pero no me queda claro para que sirve `flush()`.

Ejemplo:

```
var fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
fileOutputStream.write(bitmapBytes)
fileOutputStream.flush()
fileOutputStream.close()
```

Comment: Hola David!, sería buena idea agregaras el código de como estas haciendo uso de flush() en Kotlin, tu pregunta puede ser de mucha ayuda a la comunidad.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/io/Flushable), tanto en `Java` como en `Kotlin` la definición del método [flush()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/io/Flushable) es:

> Vacía el stream escribiendo cualquier salida almacenada en el stream
> subyacente.

Cuando estas haciendo uso de un stream, como ejemplo cuando pasamos información a un archivo, en ocasiones se mantiene información en la clase que esta manejando el stream, con [flush()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/io/Flushable) se obliga a que pase toda la información.

Puedes usar [close()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/io/Closeable) al terminar la lectura de información, **pero para asegurar el envió de los datos pero sin cerrar el stream usamos [flush()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/io/Flushable)**.

Ejemplo:

```
fun copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream: InputStream, outputStream: FileOutputStream) {
    val buffer = ByteArray(2048)
    inputStream.use { input ->
        outputStream.use { fileOut ->  
            while (true) {
                val length = input.read(buffer)
                if (length <= 0)
                    break
                fileOut.write(buffer, 0, length)
            }
            //Aseguramos enviar toda la información.
            fileOut.flush()
            //Cerramos Stream.
            fileOut.close()
        }
    }
    inputStream.close()
}
```

Comment: Me resolviste mi duda, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 12):

Un Flushable es un destino de datos que se puede vaciar. Se invoca el método de vaciado para escribir cualquier salida almacenada en búfer en la secuencia subyacente.

El método `flush()` sirve para vaciar la secuencia escribiendo cualquier salida almacenada en la secuencia subyacente.

Dicho de otra manera, luego de grabar con el método `write` se llama al método `flush` para que vuelque todos los datos que pueden haber quedado en el buffer y se procede al cerrado del archivo con `close`.

Fuente:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/io/Flushable

Ejemplo donde trabajan con `flush`:
https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/kotlinparaandroidya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=14&codigo=62&inicio=0

Comment: Ya entiendo, muchas gracias :)